# How can I delete fancyhdr headrule on chapter pages (redefining fancypagestyle{plain} not working)

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, rules

For a project, I need to have a fancyhdr headrule on regular pages but not on pages with a \part title and with a \chapter title.

I have tried this :

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
```

But as you can see on the picture below, the headrule is still here (this is a \chapter page, as you will see on my code I have changed the format):

[image]

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[paperheight=240mm,paperwidth=160mm, left=22mm, right = 20mm, top = 20mm, bottom = 22mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\fancyfoot[LO]{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE]{}



% **************************
% Headerfooter alignment
% **************************

\newlength\FHoffset
\setlength\FHoffset{0mm}
\addtolength\headwidth{2\FHoffset}
\fancyheadoffset{\FHoffset}
\newlength\FHleft
\newlength\FHright
\setlength\FHright{19mm}

\newbox\FHline
\setbox\FHline=\hbox{\hsize=\paperwidth%
\hspace*{\FHleft}%
\rule{\dimexpr\headwidth-\FHleft-\FHright\relax}{\headrulewidth}\hspace*{\FHright}%
}
\renewcommand\headrule{\vskip-.7\baselineskip\copy\FHline}


% **************************
% Formating \chapter --> Partie 1
% **************************

\newcommand\filetPartie[1][1cm]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.3pt]
    \draw(31.8mm,-44.9mm) -- (69.8mm,-44.9mm);%
}


\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\filetPartie[1cm]
\vspace{3.3cm}

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\begin{center}
\textsc{Partie} \thechapter\
\end{center}
\par\nobreak
%\vskip 1cm
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\begin{center}
\Large #1\par\nobreak
\end{center}
\newpage
}}

\makeatother


\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


% Font formatting packages

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}


\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` inside definition of `\@makechapterhead` so a blank page style will be used for that pages.

Comment: It's working, thank you !

Comment: Observe that it should work only for chapter heads, not for part heads. Also, remove that lines after `\makeatother` regarding the page style.